# How do I place attachments on the side of other objects?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I want to create a set of launch configurations to come together and create a ship I can build in orbit. To do this, I want to be able to put parts only on one face, like on the side of the orange fuel pod. I have seen downloadable models with this, but I am pretty new to this. Can someone explain how?

http://kerbalspaceport.com/need-fuel-in-space-use-this-orbital-fuel-can/

Comment: Since you already have examples, could you post a picture of what you want to do?

Comment: So, based on the link you've provided, you want to attach things like docking ports, that normally only connect to the 'top' or 'bottom' of a cylinder, onto the sides?

Comment: @TrentHawkins That would make sense except docking ports and other objects will go on the sides without any special finagling. The only way he could be having trouble putting them on is if there isn't enough room so they keep trying to snap to the top/bottom.

Comment: @Lawton Your answer was what I was originally figuring was the answer, but based on the asker's comment, I'm trying to get a better idea of what the issue is. I know I often have trouble attaching things like docking ports to the side of things unless I manually rotate them. I also have trouble placing a single non-mirrored part on if I have to pass over any other mirrored parts, as that tends to override my symmetry settings.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Correct. That is what I'm am attempting to do; I want to put a dual dock set up on one side of one of these orange tanks.

Comment: @Lawton If there is nothing special to allow me to put these on the side of the object without having to connect to the green sphere, then what feature am I not using?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured out the solution...
BZ-52 Radial Attachment Point...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the symmetry mode to 1 face only. You can do this either by clicking the symmetry icon until it shows one icon, or by pressing X (by default) until you cycle to 1 face only. The icon is the one shown in this picture, though it may looks slightly different due to mods/version[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. I know that I only want one part, but in this editor I would like to be able to place said object to, say, the top of this cockpit on the black area.

Comment: You will need to improve your question then. I'm not certain what you are asking if its not about the symmetry function. If you could add some screenshots it may help